# APK Files served with laravel response download method getting there extension changed on Chrome Mobile

Tags: php, laravel, download, apk, laravel-8

I am serving an APK file to the user to download on there mobile but somehow its extension is changed and .zip is appended to it. Below is my code:

```
return response()->download(public_path('/releases/' . $APKFile),'app-release.apk',['Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive']);
```

With the above code, app-release.apk file becomes app-release.apk.zip on download when the user download it on an android device, specifically on Chrome Mobile.

But this works perfectly okay on Desktop and PCs.

Comment: What `Content-Disposition` header (if any) does this respond with? If none, or one that does not explicitly specify the file name to use, try and add it yourself. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: @CBroe I tried using this - Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="app-release.apk" but still the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is problem on Headers format, either misstype or lack of information to specify the file is an .apk, so here is the code

```
public function downloadApk()
{
    $filePath = public_path('File_Storage/Application.apk');
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="Application.apk"',
    ];

    return response()->download($filePath, 'Application.apk', $headers);
}
```

The .apk file were stored inside **public/File_Storage/**, This code works fine on Laravel 8.